# How to copy Prometheus data to ELK?

Tags: prometheus, elk

We have kubernetes cluster that have ELK running and Prometheus. I would like to use only Kibana to see all in one place (grafana is good option too, but less tools is needed). As log aggregator we use logstash. I would like to get Prometheus data to see in Kibana.
Maybe someone already did it? :)

Answer (score 2):

To keep all your data in ELK stack I would suggest using [metricbeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/master/metricbeat-module-prometheus.html) with Prometheus module.

Comment: Thanks @FL3SH seams it is fit our needs.